# How to print meaningfull error messages to the user through JsonResponse and Django

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to print something relevant to the user using this Django code:

```
try:
    //do things
    return JsonResponse({})
except Exception as e:
    msg = "There was an error processing your request. " \
          "Please do that. (%s)?" % e.message
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'message': msg}, status=500)
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{% url "create_stats" %}',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#aform").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        window.location ="{% url "charts" %}";
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error){
       $("#msg-label").text('Action did not finish successfully. ' + xhr.responseText);

    }
```

However I get this:

```
Action did not finish successfully. {"status": "false", "message": "There was an error processing preference authorities. Please do that. (64)?"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass the exceptions to client as it could potentially leak some sensitive information.

Anyway during the development process just raise an exception, so it will print the whole traceback so you can see the context of what/where exactly the problem is. It wont work with the JSON in browser as you would expect, but you can display the raw response in browser's developer tools.